# auto width parent div with float childrens

Tags: html, css

i was trying to make a filter list and i found a problem. I have a DIV parent with

```
width: auto; 
padding: 8px;
white-space: nowrap;
```

and inside it i got 2 input[type="text"] with

```
float: left;
```

now on Chrome they align 1 near another but in IE8 the 2nd input goes under the 1st one.

Thank you in advance, Daniel.

Comment: What are the width of your inputs and what is the width of the parent of your parent div?

Comment: Input elements are inline-elements and do not need a float: left

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `float:left`

```
.wrap{
    width: auto; 
padding: 8px;
white-space: nowrap;
    background:violet;
    overflow:auto
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/An4wE/2/)**

Comment: "overflow: auto" produces scrollbars on Firefox 3.6 if content gets too big. Take care of this.